# How do you say 'entrechat' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I can't find 'entrechat' in the standard sources, and Google Translate throws its hands up at it.

Comment: Can you give more context? This is a ballet term, and if that is the topic you may as well just put it in italics. Sometimes however it is used as a sarcastic expression for an ordinary jump.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is *kapriolo*. According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#kapriolo):

> **kapriolo**
>
> **1** Kaprica, petola salto en kapra maniero.
>
> **2** Salto, dum kiu dancisto kunfrapas la piedojn.
>
> **3** Salto, dum kiu ĉevalo, estante en la aero, kalcitras.

Comment: I don’t know anything about ballet, but it sounds like _entrechat_ is a very specific dance move where the dancer jumps and crosses the legs rather than just hitting the feet together. I wonder if _kapriolo_ is more like _cabriole_ which seems to be a different move. Both words are related to goats jumping around.

Comment: I suspect that the Spanish-Esperanto Dictionary translates it as _kapriolo_ (loosely describing it as a kind of jump in dance) because it is not a technical dictionary about the art of dancing. I think the word may be useful if the context is not going too much into ballet technicalities. For the technical definition you may use _entrechat_ as is, in Esperanto, according to [Terminaro de klasika dancado](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminaro_de_klasika_dancado#Entrechat).

Comment: Mi pensas, ke estas malĝoja rezigni la katon por la kapro ;)